# How to link VBA app against debug mode COM DLL

Tags: excel-2007, excel, vba, visual-studio

I am trying to debug an VBA excel app that invokes some functions from a C++ COM DLL.
I have added type library of the COM DDL in Tools--->References.
If i build the DLL in debug mode, VBA app complains about not finding the dll at run-time.
When i build the DLL in release mode, i am unable to debug it.

Does anyone knows how to link VBA against debug mode COM DLL ?

Comment: Are you running Excel on the development machine where Visual C++ is installed?

Comment: Yes, i am running both on the same machine.

Answer (score 0):

Once you set the dll in Debug mode, you will have to add the project file as reference in vba editor before running the macro that is using code of C++ COM DLL. You are also supposed to have the source code with you.